# Authorization - Angular + Spring + wso2

Tags: angular, spring, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I've never implemented an application that needed to handle user authentication and authorization.

Now I'm trying to implement an app that has a front-end build with angular and a back-end build with spring security. And I want to user Wso2 identity server as an identity provider.

My doubt is, should i use a library like angular-oauth2-oidc or Asgardeo in the front-end and call the endpoint for the identity server authorization server from here; or should I call an api that I should implement in the backend and that api calls the identity server authorization server endpoint and returns to the front-end the access token generated?

Answer (score 0):

Use an OIDC client lib for Angular. My favorite is [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client). It will handle:

- redirections to and from authorization-server
- exchange of authorization code for tokens
- access-token refreshing (silently, just before it expires)
- requests authorization (HTTP interceptor to set authorization header with access-token)

It also provides with Angular route guard to redirect to login when an unauthorized user tries to activate a protected route.